# ReactJS Tutorial Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting parsing error when using reactJS tutorial.

./src/index.js
  Line 12:  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...?

```
  white-space: pre-wrap;"></div><div id="root"></div>
                                ^
```

This is the code shared on the reactjs.org. but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Wrap that inside another tag. `<>{{the code that you are using here}}</>`

Comment: Even that didn't work                                                                                            
                                                                                                       
                                                                                                       
'code' /src/index.js
  Line 15:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  13 | <script>
  14 | window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
> 15 |   document.body.classList.add('mouse-navigation');
     |                                                  ^

Comment: This a different error in your java script. The previous one was reactDOM issue which is resolved and ended up with some other error. Can you post the script part completely?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you cannot have something like that in JSX:

```
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
```

It must be wrap like this, note that Fragment could be any component that can accept child component, Fragment is to wrap stuff when usually you wouldn't need to had a div but must comply with JSX syntax, you need to import it from React:

```
<Fragment>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
</Fragment>
```

After that if you get other errors not related to this one then they are probably not related.

Answer (score 0):

Take all your html elemnts and wrap them in between a pair of divs

```
<div>
   <...>
   </...>
</div>
```